# What is the fastest way to land?

Tags: apex-legends

What's the fastest and quickest way to land at a specific spot in Apex Legends?  In Fortnite, I would drop about 3 map tiles away from a spot I wanted to drop, however in this game, the dropship seems to fly slower than gliding towards my location.

In addition, I have seen squads do weird things when dropping. Some fly straight down, while some others seem to fly straight for a bit, dip down for a brief moment, then fly straight again.

What's the trick to landing? What's the fastest way to drop?

Comment: Totally depends on where you want to land, how far away it is, what you mean with "fastest" and how the path to the desired location is

Comment: Yes, it depends on where you're landing, but there should also be a way to expedite medium-long range drops besides straight down drops.  How do people estimate the distance to drop from the aircraft to their intended destination? This is why I have brought up Fortnite as an example --  a good rule of thumb in that game is to drop 2-3 tiles before the location where you want to drop.

Comment: For an exact distance you can put a marker on the map and look in its direction. you will be given a distance in meters. I prefer to aim for the spot I want to land on. this results in the "shortest" path, though its not the fastest way. If the drop follows actual physics, then a `Brachistochrone Curve` is fastest. [This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/apexlegends/comments/aqnfb9/the_actual_mathematically_fastest_way_to_reach_a/) has it all in there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biggest difference between Fortnite and Apex is that you are not forced to glide down the ground in Apex. This means you can land directly on top of your destination as opposed to "x tiles away".

The reason you see teams dipping for a bit is to rebuild their speed. You can see your current speed indicated at the left of your screen as you drop in (shown below). The steeper the angle of descent, the faster you will pick up speed, and a lower angle means faster loss of speed.

If your intended location is close to the ship you will want to do a straight dive down to your destination, simple as that.

Doing a long distance drop is a bit more difficult because of the speed mechanic, you won't get very far flying flat all the way down. Keeping your speed in the 135-145 range should allow you to cross the majority of, if not the entire map. When you come near 135 just dip down to recover some speed and level out again around 145.

[image]

Comment: Dayum, how did you reach 154.1?! The max speed I ever got (even when going straight down) was around 148, but never above 150

Comment: @XtremeBaumer The picture isn't mine, but it takes some time for your character to turn in air to where you are looking. You might be looking straight down but your character might not have caught up yet. Straight down should be able to reach 159+.